# OpenGL Depth Buffer

Tags: opengl, buffer, depth

I am a complete novice to OpenGL, so I am just trying out some tests with it. I have a rectangle that I can rotate and translate around, and all is well.

The problem is, when I translate it below 1.0 Z, it disappears! 
I read about the depth buffer, and it says that its depth shouldn't be touched. Is there a way to work around this that I am completely missing? (Probably) If so, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely due to an incorrect projection matrix.  When you setup your projection matrix, you need to specify the clipping planes (`zNear` and `zFar`) - anything outside of these will get "clipped away" and not show up.

For details, see [gluPerspective](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml).

Comment: Sounds about right. Is there any way to do it without GLU, though?

Comment: @SuperDisk Yeah - use glFrustum: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrustum.xml